# How not to reset ID's on reload in React?

Tags: reactjs, ids

In my React ToDo list, the todos keep having the same ID's after reloading the App.

So, if I start setting todos, they will have the id's correctly numbered: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,...

```
todos: [{id: 0, text: "Create PWA", date: 1601244000000, completed: false},…]
0: {id: 0, text: "Create PWA", date: 1601244000000, completed: false}
1: {id: 1, text: "Use Hooks for Gorilla sound once", date: 1601416800000, completed: false}
...
```

However, If I reload, the ID's will reset:

```
todos: [{id: 0, text: "Create PWA", date: 1601244000000, completed: false},…]
0: {id: 0, text: "Create PWA", date: 1601244000000, completed: false}
1: {id: 1, text: "Use Hooks for Gorilla sound once", date: 1601416800000, completed: false}
2: {id: 0, text: "dsadasd", date: 1600812000000, completed: false}
...
```

Any ideas how to solve?
[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-saha-dmbm6)

Comment: What do you mean "reload"? Also, try to include the minimal, relevant code here, rather than a link to a sandbox with a bunch of files which we then need to sort through

Comment: Sharing your project and hoping someone to debug it is not how SO works, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on a quick glance, your problem seems to be from the way you set the id like from the following:

```
let nextTodoId = 0;

export const addTodo = (todo) => ({
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    todo
});
```

it's fine on first load because it will be zero and then each item added it will be incremented, but on reload it will be 0 again.

the way to fix this will be to first check if state is present in local storage and then get the id of the last item in the list and then use that as the base id - if there is no last id, just make it 0 again

so something like the following should work

```
function getBaseId() {
    const serialzedState = localStorage.getItem("state");
    if (serialzedState === null) return 0;
    const parsedState = JSON.parse(serialzedState);
    const todos = parsedState.todos
    return todos[todos.length - 1].id;
}

let nextTodoId = getBaseId();
```

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the idea. Seem ur on the good track, but the issue I get now is that the last ID (before reload) and first (after reload) are the same number. Im playing to see how to fix it, but didnt mange so far...

Comment: sorry I didn't see the bit where you were doing `nextTodoId++` to increment the id, if that's the case then we will just need to add one to the base id that is returned from successfully parsing the local storage state. the other option would be to do `nextTodoId++` before you return the todo object in the `addTodo` function

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the response. Now I managed to fix this by installing UUID. Super easy!

Comment: Also another way could be using `React.useMemo` if your components are being forced to re-render by a higher level component.